# Debug Helidon MP Application

Tags: helidon

I'm new to Helidon MP and I'm trying to implement my first microservice.
I wasn't able to find out how to debug my application, can someone point me to a good example or documentation? Is there a way to start the runtime in debug mode or something like this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helidon MP is not really a runtime in the sense of being an application server.  It's primarily a collection of libraries you add to your project.  Therefore you debug programs that use Helidon like you would debug any other Java application, i.e. by adding Java debug switches to the command line.

Here is the output from `java -agentlib:jdwp=help`, which should get you started with basic Java debugging:

```
$ $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v11)/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=help
               Java Debugger JDWP Agent Library
               --------------------------------

  (see http://java.sun.com/products/jpda for more information)

jdwp usage: java -agentlib:jdwp=[help]|[<option>=<value>, ...]

Option Name and Value            Description                       Default
---------------------            -----------                       -------
suspend=y|n                      wait on startup?                  y
transport=<name>                 transport spec                    none
address=<listen/attach address>  transport spec                    ""
server=y|n                       listen for debugger?              n
launch=<command line>            run debugger on event             none
onthrow=<exception name>         debug on throw                    none
onuncaught=y|n                   debug on any uncaught?            n
timeout=<timeout value>          for listen/attach in milliseconds n
mutf8=y|n                        output modified utf-8             n
quiet=y|n                        control over terminal messages    n

Obsolete Options
----------------
strict=y|n
stdalloc=y|n

Examples
--------
  - Using sockets connect to a debugger at a specific address:
    java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:8000 ...
  - Using sockets listen for a debugger to attach:
    java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y ...

Notes
-----
  - A timeout value of 0 (the default) is no timeout.

Warnings
--------
  - The older -Xrunjdwp interface can still be used, but will be removed in
    a future release, for example:
        java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:[help]|[<option>=<value>, ...]
```

Comment: (It is worth noting that the URL output by the tool for "more information" has been dead for over a decade.  Probably the new "for more information" URL should be https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jpda/architecture.html.)

Comment: Thank you, that's what I also came to. I now can debug in my IDE but I think ti would be great to have it integrated in the helidon-cli tool or to have a maven plugin.

Comment: It does support it, use `helidon dev --app-debug` to start the dev-loop in debug mode. It will print the debug port once the app is started. see `helidon help dev` for more information.